# Generate random numbers with loop in interval VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, loops, random, integer, intervals

How to generate random number loop in interval between 0-99 in title bar like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n6cvxlpjzklys80/vb.gif

I am able to generate random numbers in menu bar but unable to loop them in specific interval.

```
Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((99 * Rnd()) + 1))
Dim randomnumber As String = "My random no. between " & value.ToString

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.Text = randomnumber

    End Sub
```

Comment: What interval do you want them to be generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a windows forms timer to your project and this code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Timer1.Interval = 100 '10 per second
    Me.Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Shared prng As New Random
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.Text = "My random no. between " & prng.Next(100)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks :) it works but what if I wanted a random numbers between someting like 10-60?

Comment: Thanks again :) got it! **prng.Next(10, 60 + 1)**